# How to include modules from a different directory in puppet

Tags: puppet

My module tree is like this

```
   - modules
     - socle1
       - stdlib
     - socle2
       - ntp
```

How do I include the stdlib module in my `site.pp`?

I have tried `include socle1::stdlib` and it is not working .

Should I modify the `environment.conf` for the directory environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to arrange your modules in separate trees, then you may do so.  You should then include each base path in your environment's modulepath, and refer to the modules by their regular names.  Note in particular that altering the path to a module does not change its name or the names of any of the classes or types it defines -- the path influences only whether the autoloader can find them.

I strongly advise against making subdirectories of the standard module directory, however.  Instead, if you want to group modules in multiple directories then create parallel module directories for that purpose:

```
- modules
- socle1
  - stdlib
- socle2
  - ntp
```

> Should I modify the environment.conf for the directory environment?

In order to support any module directories beyond or instead of the default, yes, you should.  The puppet documentation describes [how to configure your environment's modulepath](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.6/reference/environments_creating.html#the-modulepath).  But do consider following @MattSchuchard's advice and instead restricting yourself to the standard module directories.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to put modules inside of other modules. Your tree should be like:

```
- modules
  - socle1
  - stdlib
  - socle2
  - ntp
```

Also, you would very rarely `include stdlib`, because stdlib is almost entirely a type/function module, so you would only reference its types and functions. You would not be declaring its classes unless you were planning on using the stages functionality it provides (thanks to John Bollinger for corrections to this paragraph).

However, declaring the `ntp` module in your `site.pp` is as simple as:

```
include ntp
```

or:

```
class { 'ntp': }
```

inside of your `node { }`.

Comment: thanks for you response, but socle1 is not a module, it's simply a directory which contain modules. i'm using r10k and it will help me a lot organising modules like this

Comment: r10k would not organize your modules inside of subdirectories though. Also there is no reason to use subdirectories and that is going to confuse Puppet.

Comment: `stdlib` (at least the current version) is not a pure function/type module.  It has an eponymous class, so you *can* `include stdlib`.  That class itself includes `::stdlib::stages`, which declares a set of standard(-ish) run stages, so including stdlib is not without effect.  Nevertheless, it's still doubtful that the OP actually wants to do that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger StackOverflow seems to have lost our comments here from yesterday, but basically I could not remember if stdlib has to be included/declared to use stages and didn't bother to check, so thanks for clarifying that info.

Answer (score -1):

In your init.pp

`class classname ( parameters ) {
  include ::socle2::ntp
 }`

Try this and tell me if this works or not!

Comment: I have always error  Could not find class ::socle::ntp

Comment: Instead of including stdlib in your site.pp, why don't you include it in the module you have created? You can include in init.pp!