# Unable to call nested custom module - "Could not find class" error

Tags: puppet

I have created a custom module and i would like to keep it within a sub-directory (category) because there are several components that should logically fall under that category. So to segregate things in a better way, i created the following structure.

```
- hieradata
- manifests
- modules
    - infra
        - git
            - files
            - manifests
                - init.pp
                - install.pp
                - configure.pp
        - monitoring
        - etc
- templates

$ cat modules/infra/git/manifests/init.pp
class infra::git {}

$ cat modules/infra/git/manifests/install.pp
class infra::git::install {
    file { 'Install Git':
        ...
        ...
    }
}

$ cat manifests/site.pp
node abc.com {
    include infra::git::install
}
```

Now on the puppet agent, when i try `puppet agent -t`, i get the following error:

```
ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [x64-mingw32]

C:\puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: {"message":"Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::infra::git::install for abc.com at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:15:2 on node abc.com","issue_kind":"RUNTIME_ERROR"}
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I have already read [this](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_namespaces.html) link but that suggests keeping custom module *directly* under main `modules` directory, which is not how i would like to structure the directories.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of solving this specific technical problem for you, I will go ahead and help you solve the larger architecture/design problem that this technical problem stems from: https://docs.puppet.com/pe/2016.5/r_n_p_intro.html

Comment: @MattSchuchard: I have gone through roles and profiles few days back and i definitely feel that's how my overall Puppet structure should look like but i'm planning to do it in the next refactoring phase. Can you let me know what's wrong with my current approach? Is it just some syntactical issue or will this approach just won't work?

Comment: Check here for temporary workarounds from John Bollinger and myself on your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202383/how-to-include-modules-from-a-different-directory-in-puppet. Note both of us recommend against doing what you have described in your question though. The faster you can get to roles and profiles given your current layout, the better.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MattSchuchard! It worked. :) I will definitely try to do the refactoring as soon as possible.

Comment: Sounds great. The reason I exhort you to move quickly is because this approach will accumulate some measure of technical debt in the interim,

Comment: I can imagine that. Actually, there are many things moving in parallel right now. Looking into Hiera as to how it can be utilized to manage data for different environments (QA, UAT, Production), parameterization of classes, deployment etc. but yes, roles and profiles will also happen sometime soon.